# I need help understanding a error message

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is an error message that keeps coming up as I try to disply results on my program.

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
   at AddressBookIO.getEntriesString(AddressBookIO.java:38)
   at AddressBookEntryApp.main(AddressBookEntryApp.java:42)
```

I am almost certain my code is correct. My program does everything it is suppose to do except display my results. The ""main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" is the part that confuses me.

Heres the code for AddressBookIO.java, and AddressBookEntryApp

```
import java.io.*;

public class AddressBookIO
{
private static File addressBookFile = new File("address_book.txt");
private static final String FIELD_SEP = "\t";
private static final int COL_WIDTH = 20;

// use this method to return a string that displays
// all entries in the address_book.txt file
public static String getEntriesString()
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try
    {
        checkFile();

        in = new BufferedReader(
             new FileReader(addressBookFile));

        // define the string and set a header
        String entriesString = "";
        entriesString = padWithSpaces("Name", COL_WIDTH)
            + padWithSpaces("Email", COL_WIDTH)
            + padWithSpaces("Phone", COL_WIDTH)
            + "\n";

        entriesString += padWithSpaces("------------------", COL_WIDTH)
            + padWithSpaces("------------------", COL_WIDTH)
            + padWithSpaces("------------------", COL_WIDTH)
            + "\n";

        // append each line in the file to the entriesString
        String line = in.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            String[] columns = line.split(FIELD_SEP);
            String name = columns[0];
            String emailAddress = columns[1];
            String phoneNumber = columns[2];

            entriesString +=
                padWithSpaces(name, COL_WIDTH) +
                padWithSpaces(emailAddress, COL_WIDTH) +
                padWithSpaces(phoneNumber, COL_WIDTH) +
                "\n";

            line = in.readLine();
        }
        return entriesString;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        close(in);
    }
}

// use this method to append an address book entry
// to the end of the address_book.txt file
public static boolean saveEntry(AddressBookEntry entry)
{
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try
    {
        checkFile();

        // open output stream for appending
        out = new PrintWriter(
              new BufferedWriter(
              new FileWriter(addressBookFile, true)));

        // write all entry to the end of the file
        out.print(entry.getName() + FIELD_SEP);
        out.print(entry.getEmailAddress() + FIELD_SEP);
        out.print(entry.getPhoneNumber() + FIELD_SEP);
        out.println();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        close(out);
    }
    return true;
}

// a private method that creates a blank file if the file doesn't already exist
private static void checkFile() throws IOException
{
    // if the file doesn't exist, create it
    if (!addressBookFile.exists())
        addressBookFile.createNewFile();
}

// a private method that closes the I/O stream
private static void close(Closeable stream)
{
    try
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   // a private method that is used to set the width of a column
   private static String padWithSpaces(String s, int length)
{
    if (s.length() < length)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        while(sb.length() < length)
        {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    else
    {
        return s.substring(0, length);
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddressBookEntryApp
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    // display a welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Address Book application");
    System.out.println();


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    int menuNumber = 0;
    while (menuNumber != 3)
    {
        // display menu
        System.out.println("1 - List entries");
        System.out.println("2 - Add entry");
        System.out.println("3 - Exit\n");

        // get input from user
        menuNumber = Validator.getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter menu number: ", 0, 4);
        System.out.println();

        switch (menuNumber)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                String entriesString = AddressBookIO.getEntriesString();
                System.out.println(entriesString);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                // get data from user
                String name = Validator.getRequiredString(sc, "Enter name: ");
                String emailAddress = Validator.getRequiredString(sc, "Enter email address: ");
                String phoneNumber = Validator.getRequiredString(sc, "Enter phone number: ");

                // create AddressBookEntry object and fill with data
                AddressBookEntry entry = new AddressBookEntry();
                entry.setName(name);
                entry.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
                entry.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

                AddressBookIO.saveEntry(entry);

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("This entry has been saved.\n");

                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post your (relevant) code, please.

Comment: "I am almost certain my code is correct" -> well it isn't, hence the error message. Trust your compiler.

Comment: I trust it, i'm just frusterated with it.

Comment: Just a tip: When you post code like this, indicate exactly on which line the exception occurs. AddressBookIO.java:38 doesn't say much when we cannot see the line numbers in the posted source code. Sure we could copy paste into an editor and search for ourselves, but it's much easier to give advice if you indicate exactly where in the code the exception is raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown when you try to access an Index, which is more than the size of the specified array.

Try to change this :

```
while(line != null)
{
    String[] columns = line.split(FIELD_SEP);
    String name = columns[0];
    String emailAddress = columns[1];
    String phoneNumber = columns[2];

    entriesString += padWithSpaces(name, COL_WIDTH) +
                       padWithSpaces(emailAddress, COL_WIDTH) +
                       padWithSpaces(phoneNumber, COL_WIDTH) +
                       "\n";

    line = in.readLine();
}
```

to this :

```
while(line != null)
{
    String[] columns = line.split(FIELD_SEP);
    if (columns.length > 2)
    {
        String name = columns[0];
        String emailAddress = columns[1];
        String phoneNumber = columns[2];

        entriesString += padWithSpaces(name, COL_WIDTH) +
                           padWithSpaces(emailAddress, COL_WIDTH) +
                           padWithSpaces(phoneNumber, COL_WIDTH) +
                           "\n";
    }
    line = in.readLine();
}
```

Comment: @BradWhite : Your Welcome, I am Glad it did helped you somewhere :-)

Answer (score 1):

The exception means that you are accessing an array's element beyond the size of the array. So, you need to provide the details of your code to be able to let you know the cause of the issue.

Comment: +1, for the quick and right reply, before even the code has been posted :-)

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

As per your error logs..code at line no:38 in `AddressBookIO.java` is throwing this exception.

Could be here..

```
            String name = columns[0];
            String emailAddress = columns[1];
            String phoneNumber = columns[2];
```

if there is no element at either 0, 1 or 2..

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: The 1st element (index 0) of an array with *no elements* has been incorrectly accessed.

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: [index is] 0**

For instance, this would throw that exception:

```
int bad = (new int[0])[0]; // no elements :(
```

While the following is okay:

```
int ok = (new int[1])[0];  // one element, can access it!
```

I suspect it is this:

```
String[] columns = line.split(FIELD_SEP); // empty array?
String name = columns[0];                 // KABOOM!
```

In any case, check the code on the line *reported* in the exception.

> at AddressBookIO.getEntriesString(**AddressBookIO.java:38**)

Comment: I think I follow what your saying, I'm just not seeing where the fix needs to take place

Comment: @BradWhite Well, checking columns.length before trying to access something outside the bounds ... question is why does it not contain elements as expected?

Comment: I understand how to follow the error message to the line of code. I don't understand whats wrong with the code. The AddressBookIO class was the one supplied to us from the instructor.

Comment: @BradWhite well, what are the contents of `line`? **It is not as expected.** Perhaps it's an "empty string"? Whatever it is, *why* is it that way? Use a debugger to find out!

Answer (score 1):

A blank line in 'address_book.txt' perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the first element of an empty array. It doesn't exist, so you get an exception from the run time.

The array that you are trying to access is the result of the `split()` method. This will only return an empty array if you pass a string of delimiters: `"\t"`

So, there must be some lines that contain only tabs with nothing between them.

Instead of using `split()`, you should consider applying regular expression to each line. This way, you can validate the format of the line *and* apply "capture groups" at the same time to easily extract values for each field, even if they are empty strings.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)");
...
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (!m.matches()) {
  /* The line is invalid; skip it or throw an exception. */
  ...
}
String name = m.group(1);
String emailAddress = m.group(2);
String phoneNumber = m.group(3);
```